# Utilizar dos clases con Foreign Key en una API en C#

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, webapi

el problema es el siguiente, tengo un modelo con dos clases:

```
public class Paciente
    {
        [Key]
        public int idPaciente { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string ApellidoPaterno { get; set; }
        public string ApellidoMaterno { get; set; }
        public int Telefono { get; set; }
        public string Direccion { get; set; }
        public List<Lectura> Lecturas { get; set; }
    }

    public class Lectura
    {
        [Key]
        public int idLectura { get; set; }
        public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
        public int RitmoCardiaco { get; set; }
        public int SaturacionOxigeno { get; set; }
        public int idPaciente { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("idPaciente")]
        public Paciente Paciente { get; set; }
    }
```

En el DbContext tengo lo siguiente:

```
 public PacienteContext(DbContextOptions<PacienteContext> options)
            : base(options) 
        { 
        }

        public DbSet<Paciente> Pacientes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Lectura> Lecturas { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
              modelBuilder.Entity<Paciente>().HasMany(p => p.Lecturas).WithOne(b => b.Paciente).HasForeignKey(p => p.idPaciente);
        }
```

Y el controlador:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Paciente>> PostPaciente(Paciente paciente)
        {
            _context.Pacientes.Add(paciente);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetPaciente), new { id = paciente.idPaciente }, paciente);
            
        }
```

Y al momento de querer insertar algo con Postman en formato JSON

```
{
    "Nombre": "Pedro",
    "ApellidoPaterno": "Fernandez",
    "ApellidoMaterno": "Crespo",
    "Telefono": 7654321,
    "Direccion": "Av. Americana",
    "Lecturas": [{
        "Fecha": "2021-05-23",
        "RitmoCardiaco": 80,
        "SaturacionOxigeno": 80
    }]

}
```

Inserta bien los datos del Paciente, pero en la parte de Lectura lo guarda como `null`. Estoy casi seguro que me falta algo en el controlador, pero no sabría que, espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: Pero a Lecturas no le faltan datos? tu modelo dentro del item lectura tiene muchos campos que aca no estan.. y ademas Lecturas es una lista.. no se si esta bien escrito ese JSON...

Comment: @gbianchi A Lecturas en teoria su ID y el ID del paciente se rellenan automaticamente, sin necesidad de colocar su respectivo parametro, y en cuanto al Json, intente de igual manera colocarlo tipo [ { } ] y tambien la parte de lectura se guarda como nulo

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> {
>     "Nombre": "Pedro",
>     "ApellidoPaterno": "Fernandez",
>     "ApellidoMaterno": "Crespo",
>     "Telefono": 7654321,
>     "Direccion": "Av. Americana",
>     "Lecturas": {
>         "Fecha": "2021-05-23",
>         "RitmoCardiaco": 80,
>         "SaturacionOxigeno": 80
>     }
> }
> ```

Lo correcto es:

```
{
    "Nombre": "Pedro",
    "ApellidoPaterno": "Fernandez",
    "ApellidoMaterno": "Crespo",
    "Telefono": 7654321,
    "Direccion": "Av. Americana",
    "Lecturas": [
        {
            "Fecha": "2021-05-23",
            "RitmoCardiaco": 80,
            "SaturacionOxigeno": 80
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Así lo probé originalmente, y como mencioné antes, guarda los datos de la lectura como nulos, se me pasó en el post, enseguida corrijo